No module named 'pyaes'
i have project and i get this error over and over
<module>
    import pyaes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaes'
220 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.7.0, contrib hooks: 2024.6
220 INFO: Python: 3.12.3
241 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Script file 'loader-o.py' does not exist.

It should create an exe file, but it gives this error instead

PyInstaller is trying to include the pyaes module in your executable but is unable to find it. Try installing pyaes using pip
pip install pyaes

